# Software Suggestion for Managing Voice Recordings (Windows)

Tags: windows, file-management, audio, automation

I'm looking for Windows software that allows me to effectlively manage already made voice recordings. I have a series of recordings taken from an iPhone and I have extracted the files. The problem is that these are very long recordings and therefore I'm looking for software that allows me to:

- Bookmark a time in the recording
- Effectively manage multiple files (like Adobe Bridge does with images)
- Freeware or Payware
- Possibly other features, I haven't done this before and I'm sorry I'm unable to give a more professional description.

Thanks in advance to everyone who can help! If you have any other questions, please don't hesitate to ask - I will try my best to provide useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at AMV Studio?
Its primary function is convert video and audio, but it does bookmark audio files.
[A better way to see if this is right for your needs](http://www.avs4you.com/index.aspx)

Comment: From your link, the most relevant one I found was [AVS Audio Editor](http://www.avs4you.com/AVS-Audio-Editor.aspx). Is that the one you mean? I looked at it and it might do the job, but it seems like it's very specific to other tasks. I was hoping for something slightly more focused on what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your suggestion though, I will check it out and come back to you.